# Checkerboard not showing? Section of application just black?

Tags: java, swing

First off I would like to say that I understand I am asking a lot so any help would be appreciated and I thank you for your time. I am extremely grateful.

Anyway I am creating a game for my A2 coursework, most commonly known as Checkers. I have completed my code and everything works as I had planned except that the CheckerBoard itself as well as the checkerpieces do not appear to be showing.

The section of were my board should be present is just a black space. Although my board does not appear to be displaying, all of the actions I perform on it such as clicking certain section produces the planned response, and although I've checked through my code I cannot work out what I've done wrong.

Anyway if anyone could possibly spot my mistake or perhaps give me some advice I would be extremely grateful. Thank you

```
public class CheckerBoard extends JPanel implements ActionListener, MouseListener {
    // Main routine that opens an Applet that shows a CheckerBoard
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame application = new JFrame("Checkers"); // Sets the title at the top of the application as 'Checkers'
        JMenuBar bar = new JMenuBar(); // Adds the Menu Bar
        JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File"); // Adds a File Tab to the Menu Bar
        JMenu helpMenu = new JMenu("Help"); // Adds a Help Tab to the Menu Bar
        JMenuItem exit = new JMenuItem("Exit"); // Adds the Exit sub-tab as an Item of the JMenu
        JMenuItem mainMenu = new JMenuItem("Main Menu"); // Adds the Main Menu sub-tab as an Item of the JMenu
        final JMenuItem Rules = new JMenuItem("Rules"); // Adds the Rules of Checkers sub-tab as an Item of the JMenu
        helpMenu.add(Rules); // Adds the Rules of Checkers tab into the Help tab
        fileMenu.add(mainMenu);// Adds the Main Menu sub-tab into the File tab 
        fileMenu.addSeparator(); // Adds a line in between the Main Menu sub-tab and the Exit sub-tab
        fileMenu.add(exit); // Adds the Exit sub-tab into the Menu tab
        bar.add(fileMenu); // Adds the Menu tab to the Menu bar
        bar.add(helpMenu); // Adds the Help tab to the Menu Bar
        application.setJMenuBar(bar); // Adds the Menu Bar to the application window
        Rules.addActionListener(new ActionListener() // Adds a new ActionListener to the Rules sub-tab
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev)
        {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Rules,
                        "- Pieces must always move diagonally\n" +
                        "- Single pieces are limited to forward moves\n" +
                        "- Kings may move both forward and backward\n" +
                        "- When a piece is captured, it is removed from the board\n" +
                        "- If a player is able to make a capture, there is no option, the jump must be made\n" +
                        "- When a piece reaches the opponents end of the board, it is crowned and becomes a King",
                        "Rules for Checkers",
                        JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        }
        }); //This has added a JOptionPane action when my Rules sub-tab is clicked, this displays the message dialog of the JOptionPane which can be seen
        exit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() // Adds an ActionListener to the Exit Sub-tab
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev)
            {
                System.exit(0); // This means that when the Exit sub-tab is clicked, it will exit the application 
            }
        });
        CheckerBoard content = new CheckerBoard(); // Sets the CheckerBoard values into the content to be used in the next line
        application.setContentPane(content); // Container holds the values together, Content pane of the CheckerBoard
        application.pack();  // Use preferred size of content to set size of application.
        Dimension screensize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        application.setLocation( (screensize.width - application.getWidth())/2,
                (screensize.height - application.getHeight())/2 );
        application.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE ); // Sets so that the application can be exited when the application is closed
        application.setResizable(false);  // This makes it so that the user can't change the application's size.
        application.setVisible(true); // Sets it so that the application can actually be seen
    }
    private JButton NewGameButton;  // Button for starting a new game.
    private JButton ResignButton;   // Button that a player can use to end the game by resigning
    private JLabel MessageDisplay;  // Label for displaying messages to the user.

    public CheckerBoard()  {
// This is going to be a constructor, this constructor will set the layout manager for the panel to be null, it will then add components to the panel
// and it will set their bounds.

    setLayout(null);  // So that it will match my requirement specification, I will do the layout myself
    setBackground(new Color(0,120,0));  // Dark Green Background colour.
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350,250)); // The size of the Panel

    BoardComplete checkerboardData = new BoardComplete();
    add(checkerboardData); // This will create the components and add them to the content pane
    add(NewGameButton);
    add(ResignButton);
    add(MessageDisplay);

 // I will now have to produce a method to set the position and size of each component by calling its setBounds() method
    checkerboardData.setBounds(20,20,164,164); // Sets the board dimensions
    NewGameButton.setBounds(210, 60, 120, 30); 
    ResignButton.setBounds(210, 120, 120, 30); 
    MessageDisplay.setBounds(20, 200, 350, 30); 
    }   

    public class BoardComplete extends JPanel implements ActionListener, MouseListener {

    DataForCheckers checkerboardData; // This is where the data for the checkerboard is going to be kept, this board will be responsible for the
                        // generating of the lists of the legal moves then I will define at a later stage.


    boolean CheckerMatchInProgress; // In some of the actions I will be creating, I will have to check whether a game is in progress
                            // therefore this is a boolean value as it is either true or false, only two possible outcomes. 

    // The next three variables as seen below will only be valid when the game is in progress

    int ChosenRow, ChosenColumn;   // If the current player has selected a piece to
                                    //     move, these give the row and column
                                    //     containing that piece.  If no piece is
                                    //     yet selected, then ChosenRow is -1.

    int ChosenPlayer;      // This will check which user turn it is, there will be two possible values which will include DataForCheckers.RED and Checkers.Data.BLACK


    DataForMoves[] LegalMoves;  // An array containing the legal moves for the
                                //   current player.

    // The constructor will create the buttons and the labels. It will
    // listen for mouse clicks and for clicks on the buttons. It will create
    // the board and start the first game. 

    BoardComplete() {
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        addMouseListener(this);
        ResignButton = new JButton("Resign");
        ResignButton.addActionListener(this);
        NewGameButton = new JButton("New Game");
        NewGameButton.addActionListener(this);
        MessageDisplay = new JLabel("",JLabel.CENTER);
        MessageDisplay.setFont(new  Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 14));
        MessageDisplay.setForeground(Color.green);
        checkerboardData = new DataForCheckers();
    }       

    // Now I will have to draw the checkerboard pattern in Gray and LightGray
    // Just like with my CheckerBoard Class, this will draw the checkers, and if
    // a game is in progress, it will highlight the legal moves that the user can make.

    public void PaintCheckerBoard(Graphics g) {

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        // This will draw a two-pixel black border around the edges of the canvas. 

        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawRect(0,0,getSize().width-1,getSize().height-1);
        g.drawRect(1,1,getSize().width-3,getSize().height-3);

        // Draw the squares of the checkerboard and the checkers.

        for (int row = 0; row < 8; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < 8; col++) {
                if ( row % 2 == col % 2 )
                    g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
                else
                    g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
                g.fillRect(2 + col*20, 2 + row*20, 20, 20);
                switch (checkerboardData.PieceLocation(row,col)) {
                case DataForCheckers.RED:
                    g.setColor(Color.RED);
                    g.fillOval(4 + col*20, 4 + row*20, 15, 15);
                    break;
                case DataForCheckers.BLACK:
                    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                    g.fillOval(4 + col*20, 4 + row*20, 15, 15);
                    break;
                case DataForCheckers.RED_KING:
                    g.setColor(Color.RED);
                    g.fillOval(4 + col*20, 4 + row*20, 15, 15);
                    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                    g.drawString("K", 7 + col*20, 16 + row*20);
                    break;
                case DataForCheckers.BLACK_KING:
                    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                    g.fillOval(4 + col*20, 4 + row*20, 15, 15);
                    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                    g.drawString("K", 7 + col*20, 16 + row*20);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }  // end PaintCheckerBoard()
```

I understand that this is a lot to ask but any help would be greatly appreciate and I would be extremely grateful. Thank you so much

Comment: I don't get what your code does. Where is your method `CheckerBoard.BoardComplete.PaintCheckerBoard(Graphics)` invoked? Anyway, really consider making your method and variables start with a lower-case letter, your code is unreadable. For better help sooner, please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, nothing calls your `PaintCheckerBoard` method.

Check [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details about how painting works in Swing.

Essentially, you need to override the `BoardComplete`'s `paintComponent` and perform you custom painting from within it

Having said that, it would probably be easier to achieve with a `GridLayout`

Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Comment: Yeah I understand, thank you so much for your comment and time taken. I'm grateful and I really appreciate it. Thank you :)